# Referencing a list element by it's name

Tags: python

I'm trying to scan through a list of dictionary references to get the number of keys in each dictionary.  How do I go about referencing an element's name as opposed to the content of the dictionary?  Each of the elements in the audit_dicts list is a reference to an existing dictionary.

```
audit_dicts = [ osdata, weblogic, tomcat ]
for i in audit_dicts:
    print "Length of the %s dictionary is %d lines." % (i.name(), len(i))
```

I understand that it has to do with the contents type being a dictionary, but is there no way to print the name of the element in the list?  I'm essentially using the list to store all of these dictionaries, so that I can perform multiple actions on them in a single loop.  Also, is there a way to declare these dictionaries within the same loop?  What is the pythonic way of doing so?  I currently have a bout 20 different dicitonaries of data, but I've only been able to to delcare each one individually before building the dictionary from web data.

```
for i in audit_dicts:
    i = {}
```

Comment: How about using a `dict` with a name and the actual dict reference?

Comment: To clarify, you want to get the variable names `osdata`, `weblogic` and `tomcat` as strings?

Comment: @delnan - Correct!  I'm basically trying to print the name of the list element....which happens to be a pointer to a dictionary.  It sounds like there is no other way than to make another dictionary that references these dictionaries?

Comment: @sigsegv, but those aren't the names of the list elements. Those are the names of reference variables in your scripts namespace. List elements have no name.

Comment: You may benefit from reading [Drastically Improve Your Python: Understanding Python's Execution Model](http://www.jeffknupp.com/blog/2013/02/14/drastically-improve-your-python-understanding-pythons-execution-model/).

Comment: @delnan - Thanks for the book reference!  I'm new to python, so I'm trying to soak up as much as possible.

Comment: I was referring to the blog post. I actually don't know anything about that book, except that it's apparently from the same author.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Lists don't contain names, they contain references to other objects. If you want to be able to use more than just an index to refer to the elements then you should use another data structure such as a `dict`.

Comment: Or possibly a `namedtuple`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `__name__` property, if it is set for this object:

```
audit_dicts = [ osdata, weblogic, tomcat ]
for i in audit_dicts:
  name = "unknown";
  try:
    if __name__ in i:
      name = i.__name__;
  except:
    pass
  print "Length of the %s dictionary is %d lines." % (name, len(i))
```

But you better use dict instead of list:

```
audit_dicts = {
  "osdata":osdata, 
  "weblogic":weblogic, 
  "tomcat":tomcat
  }
for key in audit_dicts:
    print "Length of the %s dictionary is %d lines." % (key, len(audit_dicts[key]))
```

Comment: That gives the (unqualified) name of the object's type, or the name set at its definition if it's a function. That's almost always wrong, and in any case not necessarily the variable name used in `audit_dicts`. And the check for presence is wrong in multiple ways.

Comment: I don't see any other solution.

Comment: Then I take it you consider it impossible, because the code in this answer does not work.